# Приглашение на встречу для участников Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Приветствую дорогие друзья. Хочу пригласить вас на встречу, которая состоится 1-го, или 2-го февраля 2018 года в таверне «Сеновал», при поддержке хорошего настроения и, возможно, горячительных напитков. Окончательное решение о дате и времени будет принято по результатам голосования. Ваши соображения оставляйте в форме [регистрации](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1e1aAIjiI_mGkE0QNmn7aAhVCKEJHM-oiyO0INTU4Ses/viewform?edit_requested=true) на встречу.

Зачем идти спросите вы...

Главная задача встречи — **личное** знакомство участников.

Может быть вы хотите прозондировать почву на предмет компаньонов, для исследования какого-нибудь из IT направлений, или реализации совместного проекта? Или как истинный стратег, желаете запастись контактами впрок?
Есть желание подискутировать об устройстве "Stack Overflow на русском" с его основателем и другими участниками с глазу на глаз? 
Интересно обменяться последними слухами IT, за бокалом вина, в окружении остроумных и интересных людей?

Если хоть одно из перечисленного относится к вам, то мы надеемся иметь удовольствие видеть вас в нашей теплой компании. И, пожалуйста, [перейдите по ссылке](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1e1aAIjiI_mGkE0QNmn7aAhVCKEJHM-oiyO0INTU4Ses/viewform?edit_requested=true) и проинформируйте нас о желании принять участие, и предпочтительном времени.

**Обновление**

По результатам голосования, на данный момент лидирует пятница 2 февраля (подходит всем). Удобное начало встречи поделилось между 19:00 и 20:00. Для всех удобен центр. Как результат, вероятно, место останется тем же — «Сеновал» на ул. Декабристов 13.

Если вы заполнили форму, то в ближайшее время получите письмо–подтверждение с деталями встречи. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь задавать любые вопросы о встрече в [чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: Классная идея! Желаю вам удачи на встрече! Если такая встреча будет в Москве - обязательно приду, особенно на безалкогольный вариант.

Comment: Идея классная, но не всем(ну мне точно) удобно добираться до центра. Мне например 1.5 часа.

Comment: @АнтонСорокин Подскажите, есть ли у вас другие идеи? Если есть кто–то, кому добираться до центра тоже 1.5 часа, но с другой стороны, то встреча в центре, так сказать, на нейтральной территории, выглядит вполне приемлемым решением!

Comment: Бокал​ ​вина ++

Comment: Как говорится, "лучше вы к нам" :) Но рад за тех, кто встретится

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это да, Невский конечно самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Невский это все же немного абстрактно, возможно будут предложения о конкретном месте?

Comment: я так и не понял о каком городе идет речь

Comment: @RomaRomin Санкт–Петербург, Россия.

Comment: Очень-очень жаль, что не в Москве :(

Comment: "Сеновалов" целых 4 штуки :)

Comment: @PinkTux тот который на ул. Декабристов 13.

Comment: Надо бы в посте примерную дату указать, а то я уже не помню что было предложено по ссылке.

Comment: Не забудьте плиз отписаться точно о месте и времени, когда определитесь

Comment: А о провинции никто снова не позаботился? :(

Comment: Есть ли какие-либо обновления по дате?

Comment: @etki 2 февраля c 19:00

Answer (score 8):

Несколько странно, что автор исходного сообщения не является сотрудником компании или хотя бы ромбовым модератором. Однако наличие красной метки, как я понимаю, говорит о том, что встреча вполне себе официальная, то есть, поддержанная компанией.

В таком случае, я предлагаю сотрудникам еще немного подсуетиться и организовать возможность вручения [знака «Не робот»](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot), который, в частности, вручался на встрече в Москве в декабре 2016 года. Да, этот знак вроде бы ограничен только лишь Stack Overflow на английском, но всё же лучше, чем ничего. Особенно учитывая тот факт, что многие участники ruSO имеют профили и на англоязычном сайте.

В идеале, конечно, было бы хорошо организовать такой знак непосредственно для участника с профилем на русскоязычном сайте.

Comment: у знака написано "50 or more attendees"

Comment: @Abyx что-то я не уверен, что в Мск было столько.

Comment: @alexolut а зачем?

Comment: @Pavel зачем что?

Comment: @alexolut знак.

Comment: @Pavel в таком случае можно ставить вопрос шире: зачем вообще нужны знаки, любые.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо! Отличное замечание! Я отправил запрос, посмотрим, что ответят. Идея в том, что знак тоже вполне реальный — это наклейка с уникальной ссылкой, которая печатается под мероприятие, ссылка действует очень ограниченное время.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на здоровье!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А я так и не понял что имеется в виду( Что за наклейка и куда ведет ссылка, а главное, — какую задачу этот механизм решает?

Comment: @Pavel Это механизм меток. Часть «геймификации» движка Формально, подобные вещи нужны для обеспечения лучшего опыта участия: участники видят перед собой цель. Знак призван: (1) показать, что вы реальный человек, а не робот; (2) возможно, стимулировать людей приходить на встречи, конференции, подходить и знакомиться друг с другом и сотрудниками компании.

Comment: @alexolut, а мне просить знак «Не осьминог» ?

Comment: @Nofate хотя бы, но я бы предложил объединить в "не робоминог".

Comment: @alexolut Знак добавил в настройках сайта. Если получится успеть  разобраться в орг. вопросах моментах — на событи знаки будут.

Comment: А как можно получить знак робот?

Comment: @polsok достаточно не иметь знака «не робот» ;)

Comment: @alexolut вообще-то недостаточно :).