# Удалить знак "Бета"

Tags: предложение, знаки

> Во время закрытой беты проголосовал 10 раз, оставил 3 сообщения с оценкой более 0, а также посетил сайт 3 раза в различные дни.

Его все-равно никто не получил и не получит.

Comment: Какую цель мы хотим этим достигнуть? Какую проблему решаем? (Есть ли она вообще, эта проблема? Значима?) Чем мешает наличие этого знака? Хотя вот знак "Аналитик" помечен как аннулирован в списке, значит, это возможно.

Comment: Знак, собственно, и не мешает, но зачем он нужен в списке, если его все-равно нельзя заработать?

Comment: "Зачем он нужен" - для истории сайта. Я правильно понимаю, что вы считаете, что любой знак, который впоследствии закроют и больше не будут выдавать нужно убирать из списка "ведь его уже не получить" и неважно, что кто-то захочет посмотреть историю по этому знаку?

Comment: Хм, об этом я не подумал. Пожалуй, Вы правы.

Comment: @AK я так понимаю, речь о знаках, которые никто не получал и не получит впредь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня есть предложение аннулировать знак, который не был и уже не будет получен на сайте: [Remove the Analytical badge from the list of badges for sites where no users have them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291119/339911)

Предложение официальными лицами пока никак не прокомментировано. Но скорее всего ничего сделано не будет. Не настолько это считается нужным, раз уж нет никакой реакции.  Видимо, кастомизировать список знаков по сайтам не так просто. Хотя вот недавно нам [добавили знак "не робот"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6765/176217), которого раньше не было и он присутствует не на всех сайтах.

Comment: А вы не хотите изменить требования в вашем вопросе на сокрытие меток, которых никто не получил и на текущий момент их невозможно получить? Это будет более универсальное и, как мне кажется, более просто реализуемое предложение. Ну или хотя бы принять [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304686/346987) той дамы.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov с точки зрения юзера сокрытие и удаление ничем друг от друга не отличаются. Это детали реализации. Принятие ответа сути дела не изменит. Хочется видеть красную метку от сотрудника компании на вопросе.

Comment: В таком виде, каком его предложили в том ответе намного проще и универсальнее это сделать и эта реализация, как мне кажется, более веротно пройдёт, чем создавать список для каждого отдельно взятого сайта и каждую отдельно взятую метку вносить. И тогда вопрос становится намного шире: не показывать **все** метки, которые никто не получил и никогда не сможет получить. Кстати, это решит все подобные вопросы на будущее, чтобы больше не создавать новые [meta-tag:feature-request]ы вроде "уберите такую-то метку с такого-то сайта".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov исходно вопрос был как раз более общий с примером про знак «аналитик», потом местные его поправили в сторону частного случая. Но это, как мне кажется, нисколько не помешает закрывать другие частные дубликатами на него.